# Is the resistance between collector and emitter is lower that of the path between collector and base?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, resistance, semiconductors

If no, pls tell me why. And if yes, my question is how can the path C-B-E be have lower resistance than that of B-E? Shouldn't the resistances of BE and CB add up cause they're in series?

Comment: A diagram would help your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The base in BJTs is very thin. Electrons there have wider thermal random motion than the systematic motion caused by Ohm's law. It's a fatal error to think the layers as resistors in series. The thermal motion (which is essential to the current gain) can be considered to bypass the base resistance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I get it now. Can you explain a bit more about the thermal motion pls

Comment: @dushyanth Everything above absolute zero kelvins vibrates or drifts randomly. That random motion isn't a consequence of heat, it IS the heat. Temperature is a conveniently scaled measure how much there's that random drift motion and vibration energy as average per a particle. The kinetic theory of heat developed gradually. You can find mathematicians Clausius, Maxwell, Bolzman, etc etc who developed it in 1800's

Answer (score 0):

Not to take away from 'user287001' answer, but the rbb' base contact region of the bipolar device can be much higher resistance than the similar regions between collector bond wire and the collector junction, or between emitter bond wire and the emitter junction.